# Uniform convergence and local uniform convergence of the sequence $n(x^\frac{1}{n}-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Why is $n(x^\frac{1}{n}-1)$ not uniformly convergent in $(0, \infty)$? I know that the given sequence converges pointwise to ln($x$). Further, is it locally uniformly convergent in every $(\frac{1}{k}, k)$ where $k \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: For locally uniformly convergent see the Dini's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem or you can prove it by definition. In a neighborhood of zero or infinity, the definition of uniform convergence cannot be true, since there is no pointvise convergence at these points (you may apply Cauchy's criterion and the property of conservation of the sign of a continuous function in a neighborhood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniformity of convergence on $(\frac 1 k,k)$ can be proved easily from the fact that $x^{1/n}=e^{\frac  1 n \ln x}=1+\frac  1 n \ln x +O(\frac  1 {n^{2}})$ uniformly on $(\frac 1 k,k)$.

Non-uniformity of convergence on $(0,\infty)$: pointwise limit is $\ln x$. If the convergence is uniform then there exists $N$ such that $|n(x^{1/n} -1)-\ln x | <1$ for all $x$ for all $n >N$. Put $x=e^{n}$ to get $n(e-2) <1$ for al $n >N$ which is a contradiction.